# My code isn't displaying the required result for kaprekar number

Tags: java, numbers

I applied all of my brain but can't figure out what to do for making a program, that finds out whether a number is [kaprekar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number) or not by using only 2 functions int countdDigits(int ) and void check(int ) except main(), display the correct result

```
import java.util.*;
class kaprekar
{
    private int countDigit(int a)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while(a>0)
        {
            a/=10;
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
    private void check(int n)
    {
        int a = countDigit(n);
        int d = (int)Math.pow(10, a);
        int sum = (a/d) + (a%d);
        if(n==sum)
            System.out.println("It is a kaprekar number");
        else
            System.out.println("It is not a kaprekar number");
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        kaprekar ob=new kaprekar();
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        ob.check(num);
    }
}
```

required result:

> Enter a number to check
>   45
>   It is a kaprekar number

actual results:

> Enter a number to check
>   45
>   It is not a kaprekar number

Comment: Great time to learn to do some debugging -- throw some extra println's into your check method to see what the method is doing, and ***why*** it's not working correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
int a = countDigit(n);
int d = (int)Math.pow(10, a);
int sum = (a/d) + (a%d);
```

You divided the number of digits with d. I think you need to divide n with d, not a.

Answer (score 0):

For Kaprekar you have to check if a sum of parts of the square number in question is the same as the number.

e.g. 45 --> 45²=2025 --> 20+25=45

following should do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class KaprekarCheck {


    private static boolean isKaprekar(int n)
    {
        String square = Long.toString(n*n);
        for (int i=1; i< square.length(); i++) {
          System.out.println("i="+i+" len="+square.length());

             int num1 = Integer.parseInt(square.substring(0, i));

             int num2 = Integer.parseInt(square.substring(i, square.length()));
          System.out.println("i="+i+" len="+square.length()+" num1="+num1+" num2="+num2);
             if (num1+num2==n) {
                  return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 9;

        if(isKaprekar(num)) 
            System.out.println("It is a kaprekar number");
        else
            System.out.println("It is not a kaprekar number");
    }
}
```